# How to avoiding to create 2 view in one time

Tags: ios

In my iOS app, I've a button and its action is create a view with a online image. 
I have to download the image first and add to the uiview then addsubview to the main view.
but between the gap, downloading the image, user can tap the button again, then my code will create another imageview with the same routine.

How can I forbid the operation when downloading image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the button by setting the `isEnabled` property on your button to NO. This will prevent any user interaction with the button. Once your download completes you can then reenable the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag like `isDownloading` to indicate wether user could or not download image.
If `isDownloading` you may not trigger the image loading function and do not create the imageView. maybe you can show a toast like "the image is downloading , please wait" to give user some reaction.

Comment: I think it's better to give user some reaction than just disable the button.But,that's your decision.:)